# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'head'

Tags: python, attributeerror

Please help! Not sure why I kept getting the error as indicated below:

```
import seaborn as sns 
%matplotlib inline 
tips = sns.load_dataset=('tips')
flights = sns.load_dataset=('flights')
tips.head()
```

And I get:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'head'`
```

Comment: what language is this in? looks like python kinda but not entirely

Comment: how is load_dataset('tips') supposed to work where is the tips dataset defined?

Comment: Remove the `=`; it assigns values to the functions instead of calling them this renders them useless and they are just strings -> hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks entirely wrong

it should be:

```
import seaborn as sns 
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
flights = sns.load_dataset('flights')
tips.head()
```

That is assuming the result of `sns.load_dataset` has a `head` member function

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested but now I get this error:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Nevermind, please disregard the previous comment regarding the TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. I rebooted the Visual Studio Code IDE and that apparently fixed the error. Thanks @UpAndAdam for the help!

Comment: if my answer is useful it would ideal for you to upvote and accept the answer